# React.js build enviroment doesn't show other routes thant the root one

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I cannot access the routes that I have set up in my app when running from the build version. I can access them on dev enviroment though when my react app runs at a different port than the server.

I have included the below in my express server in order for it to serve the react app and only the root page is showing.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my issue.

I was having the HTML anchor tags instead of the Link attribute of react-router to my code.
Replaced them accordingly and my app is operating normaly.

Answer (score 0):

React Router does all the routing in the browser, so you need to make sure that you send the `index.html` file to your users for every route.

This should be all you need:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build//static')));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build/')});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Although, with this option react is not even showing at all.

Comment: Is it a SSR or CSR project?

Comment: it is an SSR one

Comment: You can find also my repo here

https://github.com/agelosnm/digital-health-twin-thesis